# WordPress alternate post columns

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I am trying to show posts in alternated columns like in the image below. When the first row is full another one will be made but with another style. This also applies to the 3th, 4th and so on. It depends on the number of posts.

[image: alternate columns example]

Here you can see my wordpress php/html code.

```
<?php get_header();?>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
      <?php
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'case',
        'category_name' => 'website',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
      );
      $query = new WP_Query( $args );
      if ( $query->have_posts()) : 
        $i = 0; 

        while( $query->have_posts() ) : 
          $query->the_post();
        $i++;
            if($i <= 5) {
              if($i == 1) {
      ?>
                <div class="big-pane col-lg-6">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div style='background: url("<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>") no-repeat; background-size:cover; width:100%; height:100%;'></div></a>
                  <div class="text-box">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); echo" ".$i?></h1>
                    <p><?php the_field('sub_titel');?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Bekijk project</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="small-pane-holder1 col-lg-6">
                <?php 
                } 
              else { ?>
                <div class="small-pane col-lg-6">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div style='background: url("<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>") no-repeat; background-size:cover; width:100%; height:100%;'></div></a>
                  <div class="text-box">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); echo" ".$i?></h1>
                    <p><?php the_field('sub_titel');?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Bekijk project</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <?php 
                if($i == 5){ ?> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                  <?php 
                }
              }
            }
            else { 
              $i = 1; 

              if($i == 1){ ?>
                <div class="big-pane col-lg-6 pull-right">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div style='background: url("<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>") no-repeat; background-size:cover; width:100%; height:100%;'></div></a>
                  <div class="text-box">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); echo" ".$i?></h1>
                    <p><?php the_field('sub_titel');?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Bekijk project</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="small-pane-holder2 col-lg-6 ">                  
              <?php 
              } 
              else {?>
                    <div class="small-pane col-lg-6">
                      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div style='background: url("<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>") no-repeat; background-size:cover; width:100%; height:100%;'></div></a>
                      <div class="text-box">
                        <h1><?php the_title(); echo" ".$i?></h1>
                        <p><?php the_field('sub_titel');?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Bekijk project</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <?php ?>

                <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                <?php 

              } 
            } 

        endwhile; 
        echo $i;
        else: 
          echo "<p>Sorry voor de teleurstelling :(!</p>"; 
      endif; 
      wp_reset_postdata(); ?>               
    </div>   
  </div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

This code works but not good enough to achieve my goal. i made a screenshot of this code output. See below:

[image]

The problem is the last row. The big photo is aligned to the right side as the 2nd row but its style must be the same as the first row.

I still want to give a hint of which i think is causing the problem.. I can't set the `$i = 1` and the end of the while loop. every row counts from 1 to 5 but the last row is having problems(for not taking the same style as the first row). I have put the counter behind the titles.

I really tried a lot..What did i do wrong? Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is obviously problematic: `$i = 1; if($i == 1)...` You'll never get the other branch of code executing.

Comment: yea, do you know how I can fix this? I think that i should make a loop inside a loop but i don't know how to do this. can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many columns are you working with? I'm not sure what the styling/widths are for your column layout. Could you place a simple version in a codepen or jsfiddle?

You could change your loop traversal to look more like this, so it traverses the loop in 10's:

```
if($i % 10 == 1){ // returns items 1 and 11, so the right-aligned large post
}
if($i % 10 >= 2 && $i % 10 < 5) { // posts 2-4
}
if($i % 10 == 5) { // every 5th post, add the row's closing tag at the end here
}
if($i % 10 == 6) { // every 6th post, open the new row 
}
if($i % 10 >= 7 && $i % 10 < 10) { // posts 7-9
}
if($i % 10 == 0){ // every 10th post, add the second row's closing tag at the end
}
```

Alternately, this might be a good case for a flexbox layout?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it wise to use flexbox? the older version of ie do not support it. i am also going to improve my question. it is difficult for me to put a wordpress example on codepen

Comment: THis answer works good! i just have one small problem. It seems that post 10 is missing. Could not fix this.

Comment: Sorry! The last line should be if($i % 10 == 10), not == 0
Sorry about the late reply to the previous comment as well. You're correct in thinking that earlier versions of IE don't support flexbox. If you need to support IE9 and earlier, you'll have to use a more rigid solution (the above answer, basically). However, according to the most recent stats available, IE6-9 account for less than 1% of traffic. Flexbox is worth looking into for the future :)

Answer (score 0):

i find this interesting, and i think this might suite my need, am having similar design but with another issue, here is a screen shoot of what mine looks like

[here is the image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR6MP.jpg)

here is my code

```
<div class="row featured">
   <div class="grid-box  grid-box-1  item-featured">
        <a href="http://www.marchettidesign.net/fullby/demo-biggrid/2015/01/26/video-post/">
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="cat"><span>News</span></div>
                <div class="date-feat"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 26 Jan , 2015 &nbsp;                                                       
                        <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> Video
                </div>
                <h2 class="title">Video Post with Featured Image</h2>      </div>

             <div class="quad wp-post-image"> <img src="/asstes/image1.jpg"/>   </div>              
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box  grid-box-2  item-featured">  
        <a href="http://www.marchettidesign.net/fullby/demo-biggrid/2015/01/26/post-with-more-tag/">
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="cat"><span>Lifestyle</span></div>
                <div class="date-feat"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 26 Jan , 2015 &nbsp;
                <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> Video    
                </div>

                <h2 class="title">Post With More Tag</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="vm-featured"> <img src="/asstes/image1.jpg"/>   </div>                  
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box  grid-box-3  item-featured">
        <a href="http://www.marchettidesign.net/fullby/demo-biggrid/2015/01/26/vimeo-video-post/">
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="cat"><span>What's New</span></div>
                <div class="date-feat"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 26 Jan , 2015 &nbsp;
                </div>
                <h2 class="title">Vimeo Video Post</h2>
            </div>
             <div class="quad wp-post-image"> <img src="/asstes/image1.jpg"/>   </div> 
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-box  grid-box-4  item-featured">
        <a href="http://www.marchettidesign.net/fullby/demo-biggrid/2015/01/26/post-with-image-and-text/">
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="cat"><span>News</span></div>
                <div class="date-feat"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 26 Jan , 2015 &nbsp;
                </div>

                <h2 class="title">Post with Image and text</h2>

            </div>


             <div class="quad wp-post-image"> <img src="/asstes/image1.jpg"/>   </div>                  
        </a>

    </div>
```

Comment: Because your grid-box divs are all labelled sequentially, you should be able to style these with CSS. THIS might be a good use case for flexbox if you think of the flexbox in four "columns". If you want to use the above answer, change % 10 to % 4 and iterate through them like that. I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to do that though, as there are more elegant solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

i noticed you add a class for the next 4 small pane, after the first big pane , however i wanted to ask if you have any ideal on how i could handle counter for the loop individually till it gets to 5, i.e

```
counter 1 = has content ,
counter 2 = has content , 
counter 4 = has content , 
counter 5 = has content,
```

i have although achieved something like this with the bellow code, but i would love to use your format.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :
$count = 0; $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $count++;
    if ($count <= 1 && $paged === 1) :
        if ($count === 1) echo '<div class="break"><h2>first</h2></div>'; ?>
        <div class="first-three">
            <?php the_title() ?>
        </div>
    <?php elseif (1 < $count && $count <= 2 && $paged === 1) :
        if ($count === 2) echo '<div class="break"><h2>secound</h2></div>'; ?>
        <div class="next-four">
            <?php the_title() ?>
        </div>
    <?php elseif (2 < $count && $count <= 3 && $paged === 1) :
        if ($count === 3) echo '<div class="break"><h2>third</h2></div>'; ?>
        <div class="next-six">
            <?php the_title() ?>
        </div>
    <?php elseif (3 < $count && $count <= 4 && $paged === 1) :
        if ($count === 4) echo '<div class="break"><h2>forrth</h2></div>'; ?>
        <div class="next-other-six">
            <?php the_title() ?>
        </div>
    <?php elseif (4 < $count && $count <= 5 && $paged === 1) :
        if ($count === 5) echo '<div class="break"><h2>fifth one</h2></div>'; ?>
        <div class="next-four">
            <?php the_title() ?>
        </div>

        <?php elseif (5 < $count && $count <= 6 && $paged === 1) :
        if ($count === 6) echo '<div class="break"><h2>sixth one</h2></div>'; ?>
        <div class="next-four">
            <?php the_title() ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;
endwhile; ?>
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('Older posts'); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer posts'); ?></div><?php
endif;

?>
```

More preferably i would love it to be in your own format.
thanks in advance.